# Tortoise SVN - Update to a older revision, make change and cascade it to the HEAD

Tags: tortoisesvn

I was wondering if the following is possible using Tortoise SVN

1. Update working copy to a older revision
2. Make some changes and commit.
3. Go back to the HEAD
4. Merge the changes from the commit in Step 2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not possible - starting from step 2

```
svn ci -m "123"
Sending        file.txt
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File 'Z:\wc\file.txt' is out of date
svn: E160028: File '/trunk/file.txt' is out of date
```

**WC:**

```
svn log -q
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:53:57 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:53:32 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:53:09 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:50:27 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Repo:**

```
svn log -q file:///Z:/repo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:58:43 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:56:00 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:54:31 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:53:57 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:53:32 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:53:09 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2012-12-11 06:50:27 +0600 (Вт, 11 дек 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Explanation (short version)**

subversion history is linear (inside node), not DAG, i.e - all changes have to appear after and based on HEAD state. After update to some old revision and editing source of this revision in order to save and integrate changes you have

- `svn up to HEAD` (and merge local changes with HEAD), commit new revision with  merged results

OR

- switch to any other (new) tree (branch), commit branch, merge branch with old tree

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I addressed it by creating a new branch from the older revision, switched my WC to the branch, commit the changes from WC. Now, will switch back to HEAD and merge changes from branch into HEAD.